# The right React Component PropTypes for es6 (Weak) Maps, Sets

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to force the user to pass an [es6 Map object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to a React component using PropTypes, like this for example:

```
static propTypes = {
  elementsMap: React.PropTypes.map(React.PropTypes.string, editorPropTypes.element).isRequired,
}
```

But looks like there is nothing like this in React. ([The official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#prop-validation)).

Answer (score 32):

```
elementsMap: p.instanceOf(Map).isRequired
```

Comment: but what about type of set's elements?
Like we can do with an array prop `arrayProp: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropType.string)`

Comment: what's `p`'? the `PropTypes` main module?

Comment: p in this case is indeed the PropTypes main module, and instanceOf is an object that can be imported from prop-types. Thus, you could simply import it

`import { instanceOf } from 'prop-types';`

and then use as propTypes:

`elementsMap: instanceOf(Map).isRequired`

Answer (score 6):

It's not convenient, but it's possible to write your own PropType.

From React's source (which it unfortunately does not expose at this point):

```
function createChainableTypeChecker(validate) {
  function checkType(isRequired, props, propName, componentName, location, propFullName) {
    componentName = componentName || ANONYMOUS;
    propFullName = propFullName || propName;
    if (props[propName] == null) {
      var locationName = ReactPropTypeLocationNames[location];
      if (isRequired) {
        return new Error('Required ' + locationName + ' `' + propFullName + '` was not specified in ' + ('`' + componentName + '`.'));
      }
      return null;
    } else {
      return validate(props, propName, componentName, location, propFullName);
    }
  }

  var chainedCheckType = checkType.bind(null, false);
  chainedCheckType.isRequired = checkType.bind(null, true);

  return chainedCheckType;
}
```

Which you can use like so:

```
const map = createChainableTypeChecker(function(props, propName, componentName, location, propFullName) {
    if (...) {
        return null; // pass the check
    }
    return new Error('Error message'); // fail the check
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using a custom property validator function (from the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html)):

```
// You can also specify a custom validator. It should return an Error
// object if the validation fails. Don't `console.warn` or throw, as this
// won't work inside `oneOfType`.
customProp: function(props, propName, componentName) {
  if (!/matchme/.test(props[propName])) {
    return new Error('Validation failed!');
  }
}
```

So that might look something like:

```
static propTypes = {
    elementMap: (props, propName) => {
        const m = props[propName];
        if (!m) { return new Error(`Required property ${propName} not supplied`); }
        if (!(m instanceof Map)) { return new Error("must be a Map"); }
        // check contents of map if you want...
    },
};
```

Comment: And how do I specify an array of these for example, or a PropTypes.Shape with this proptype inside?

Comment: Store that function as a variable (such as `MyPropTypes.mapRequired`) and just use `MyPropTypes.mapRequired` wherever you would use any other prop type like `PropType.string`.