# Storybook control returns a different propType

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I have a prop called *displayMap* which is supposed to be an object of class `Map`. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44456113/16313465) answer to declare the propType of *displayMap*.

The [controls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cC6vK.jpg) in Storybook show that the *displayMap* is actually an object and whenever I click the **SET OBJECT** button, I get this error:

> Invalid prop `displayMap` of type `Object` supplied to `component-name`, expected instance of `Map`.